# Pass BSTR from C++ DLL function to VB6 application

Tags: c++, vb6, bstr

I have this code in my VB6 app:

```
Private Declare Function FileGetParentFolder Lib "Z-FileIO.dll" _
(ByVal path As String) As String

Output.AddItem FileGetParentFolder(FileText.Text)
```

Output is a list, FileText is a text field containing a file path. My C++ DLL contains this function:

```
extern "C" BSTR ZFILEIO_API FileGetParentFolder(Path p)
{
    try {
        return SysAllocString(boost::filesystem::path(p).parent_path().c_str());
    } catch (...) {
        return SysAllocString(L"");
    }
}
```

where `Path` is typedef'd as `LPCSTR`. The argument comes into my DLL perfectly, but whatever I try to pass back, the VB6 app shows only garbage. I tried several different methods with `SysAllocStringByteLength`, casting the `SysAllocString` argument to `LPCWSTR` and other variants. Either, I only see the first letter of the string, or I see only Y's with dots, just not the real string. Does anyone know what the real method is for creating and passing valid BSTRs from C++ to VB6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this will point you in the right direction. From memory...

VB6 uses COM BSTRs (2-byte wide character strings) internally, but when communicating with external DLLs it uses single- or multi-byte strings. (Probably UTF-8, but I don't remember for sure.) Your Path typedef to LPCSTR is an ANSI string, and that's why you can receive it correctly. The return value you generate is a wide-character string, but VB is expecting an ANSI string. You'll need to use WideCharToMultiByte to convert your return value before returning it.

Seems a little odd that VB does this implicit conversion, but that's the way it is. (As far as I remember.)

Comment: +1 See also [Microsoft's notes on calling C DLls from VB](http://vb.mvps.org/tips/vb5dll.asp). Written for VB5, but never updated for VB6. However it is 99.9% relevant for VB6. All hail Karl Peterson who is hosting this document on his [wonderful VB6 site](http://vb.mvps.org/)

Comment: VB6 does not use UTF8 by default. It uses the .NET Encoding.Default encoding (typically Windows-1252 in Western Europe).

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using the function signature then you have to prepare a custom typelib for VB6 that includes this

```
[dllname("Z-FileIO.dll")]
module ZFileIO
{
    [entry("FileGetParentFolder")]
    BSTR FileGetParentFolder ([in] LPWSTR path);
};
```

In `Declare`s param-types `As String` are automagically converted to ANSI string, i.e. `LPSTR`. The only way to pass/receive a unicode string (`LPWSTR` or `BSTR`) is by using typelib API function declaration.

Other than that you can always use `As Long` params in the declaration and expect `LPWSTR`s but then the consumer will have to wrap strings in `StrPtr` on every call to the API function.