# Returning SAFEARRAY of BSTR from C++ DLL to VB6 via CComSafeArray causes string length mismatch

Tags: c++, arrays, dll, vb6, atl

I would like to pass a SAFEARRAY of BSTR from a C++ DLL to VB6. This is what my current implementation of the DLL looks like (compiled with VC2013U5 on Win7 x64 SP1):

sabstrtovb6.h:

```
#ifdef SABSTRTOVB6_EXPORTS
#define SABSTRTOVB6_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define SABSTRTOVB6_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include <OAIdl.h>

SABSTRTOVB6_API HRESULT __stdcall FnSABSTRToVB6(LPSAFEARRAY* ppSABSTR);
```

sabstrtovb6.cpp (Note: I'm allocating ANSI strings with `SysAllocStringByteLen()` because VB6 always performs a wide-char / ANSI and vice versa translation of strings when interfacing with DLLs. When the function returns, VB6 performs a wide-char conversion for each string in the array.):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "sabstrtovb6.h"

#include <atlsafe.h>

SABSTRTOVB6_API HRESULT __stdcall FnSABSTRToVB6(LPSAFEARRAY* ppSABSTR)
{
    if (!ppSABSTR)
        return E_POINTER;

    if (*ppSABSTR)
        return DISP_E_BADINDEX;

    HRESULT hr = SafeArrayDestroy(*ppSABSTR);
    if FAILED(hr)
        return hr;

    CComSafeArray<BSTR> cSABSTR(ULONG(0), LONG(0));

    cSABSTR.Add(SysAllocStringByteLen("Apple\0", strlen("Apple\0")));
    cSABSTR.Add(SysAllocStringByteLen("Orange\0", strlen("Orange\0")));
    cSABSTR.Add(SysAllocStringByteLen("Wall\0", strlen("Wall\0")));
    cSABSTR.Add(SysAllocStringByteLen("Bananas\0", strlen("Bananas\0")));
    cSABSTR.Add(SysAllocStringByteLen("Fax\0", strlen("Fax\0")));

    *ppSABSTR = cSABSTR.Detach();

    return S_OK;
}
```

All works well, except that the length of some strings is mismatched by an offset of a NULL character. When executing the following code in VB6...

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function FnSABSTRToVB6 Lib "sabstrtovb6" (ByRef sa() As String) As Long

Private Sub Form_Load()

ChDrive App.Path: ChDir App.Path

Dim sa() As String
Dim res As Long: res = FnSABSTRToVB6(sa)

If res >= 0 Then
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(sa)
        Debug.Print (sa(i) + ":" + CStr(Len(sa(i))))
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

... this is what the debug window display as an output:

```
Apple :6
Orange:6
Wall:4
Bananas :8
Fax :4
```

Clearly, the length indicator of Apple, Bananas, and Fax is wrong. I get the feeling that all strings with an odd-numbered length are padded with an additional byte. What is going on here? Can someone help me fix this behavior?

**UPDATE:** It seems that the CComSafeArray wrapper is causing the trouble here. When I allocate the BSTRs in the old fashioned way, as in...

```
SAFEARRAYBOUND bounds;
bounds.cElements = 5;
bounds.lLbound = 0;
*ppSABSTR = SafeArrayCreate(VT_BSTR, 1, &bounds);

SafeArrayLock(*ppSABSTR);

BSTR *SABSTRArray = (BSTR *)(*ppSABSTR)->pvData;
SABSTRArray[0] = SysAllocStringByteLen("Apple\0", strlen("Apple\0"));
SABSTRArray[1] = SysAllocStringByteLen("Orange\0", strlen("Orange\0"));
SABSTRArray[2] = SysAllocStringByteLen("Wall\0", strlen("Wall\0"));
SABSTRArray[3] = SysAllocStringByteLen("Bananas\0", strlen("Bananas\0"));
SABSTRArray[4] = SysAllocStringByteLen("Fax\0", strlen("Fax\0"));

SafeArrayUnlock(*ppSABSTR);
```

... `Len` in VB6 will display correct values:

```
Apple:5
Orange:6
Wall:4
Bananas:7
Fax:3
```

Is this a known behavior of CComSafeArray when dealing with BSTRs?

Comment: From MSDN about SysAllocStringByteLen: _The string psz can contain embedded null characters, and does not need to end with a Null_. Actual length is then right because you add an extra nil character at the end.

Comment: Yes, that cannot work.  The `CComSafeArray<BSTR>::SetAt()` accessor function dutifully creates a copy of the BSTR before storing it in the array.  That cannot work correctly on these weirdo 8-bit BSTRs, it has no way to find out that they are special.  It uses SysAllocString() to create the copy and passes the Chinese, turning 5 chars into 6.  You can't CComSafeArray, it is too safe :)

Comment: What if I'd omit the copy operation by using `CComSafeArray's` overloaded `Add` method and specifying `FALSE` for the `bCopy` parameter? Would this cause any trouble later on regarding reference counting of the managed BSTR inside the array?

Comment: Yes, that would be good.  You were leaking those BSTRs, they are not reference-counted.

Comment: You don't need \0 inside those strings as there already is one provided by the compiler. Just use L"apple" and `SysAllocString` as BSTR are unicode by design. What do you use for "length indicator in VB6", `LenB`? Stop it and just use `Len` and see that marshalling is ok, your initialization makes no sense.

Comment: @wqw `SysAllocString` won't work, since VB6 expects ANSI strings when the function returns (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134666/pass-bstr-from-c-dll-function-to-vb6-application)). Also, I'm using `Len` for calculating the string length, as indicated in my VB6 code snippet.

Comment: What's going on here and how to fix it is longer than a comment can fit. Yes, by using a `Declare` in VB6 you are suffering from the automagic ANSI<->Unicode translation VB6 does on each call.

Comment: @wqw Are you implying using a type library? That would require me to perform a registry entry, a step I'd like to avoid.

Comment: `ByVal param As String` on a `Declare` is not BSTR but LPSTR. There is no win32 API function with `param() As String` parameters. This would be treated as a safe array of LPSTRs which is weird. I would simplify function signature to a simple string and then use `Split(result, Chr$(1))` on the client side. That or use a typelib with proper string array for out param.