# Unexpected Results When Returing BSTR from DLL to Microsoft Excel VBA Application

Tags: c, vba, excel

I am writing a VBA extension in C, from what I have read VBA uses BSTR, which is just a WCHAR* with a length prefix. I have a function:

```
__declspec(dllexport) VB_STRING _stdcall getStr()
{
    return SysAllocString(L"This is a string.");
}
```

Which I call in VBA using:

```
Private Declare Function getStr Lib "main.dll" () As String

Sub do_stuff()
    Range("A1").value = getStr()
End Sub
```

However, the cell A1 will only contain 'T' rather than the entire string. Could anyone give any advice or show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: [Possibly relevant.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31409006/4088852)

Comment: Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6134666/4088852).